# How do I create dictionary from another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the best way to create a `dict`, with some attributes, from another `dict`, in Python?

For example, suppose I have the following `dict`:

```
dict1 = {
    name:          'Jaime',
    last_name:     'Rivera',
    phone_number:  '111111',
    email:         'test@gmail.com',
    password :     'xxxxxxx',
    token:         'xxxxxxx',
    secret_stuff:  'yyyyyyy'   
}
```

I'd like to obtain

```
dict2 = {
    name:          'Jaime',
    last_name:     'Rivera',
    phone_number:  '111111',
    email:         'test@gmail.com'
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

For instance:

```
keys = ['name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email']
dict2 = {x:dict1[x] for x in keys}
```

Comment: @JaimeRivera: As a defensive measure you might want to add `...if x in dict1` to the end of the dictionary comprehension expression to avoid a `KeyError` exception if any of the keys are missing.

Comment: Or if you'd prefer to swap in a default value in these cases, you could use `.get()` on the dict instead of indexing.

Comment: keys = ['name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email']
dict2 = {x:dict1[x] for x in keys} giving only keys how to use same for for getting values also for same keys.

Comment: @RomitaThakur what do you mean? `dict2` should have keys from `keys` with values from `dict1`.

Comment: @LevLevitsky no its giving only keys not the values.

Answer (score 29):

Using dict comprehension:

```
required_fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email']
dict2 = {key:value for key, value in dict1.items() if key in required_fields}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
for key in d1:
    if key in wanted_keys:
        d2[key] = d1[key]
```

**update**

I recently figured out that there's a much cleaner way of doing that with `dict` comprehensions

```
wanted_keys = set(['this_key', 'that_key'])
new_dict = {k: d1[k] for k in d1.keys() & wanted_keys}
```

Answer (score 9):

For anyone wanting a complete copy of dict1 without making a list of keys:

`dict2 = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items()}`

Comment: why don't just use copy? `from copy import copy`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you can just do `dict1.copy()`, this simply doesn't answer the question... The question is how to create a new dict with a subset of keys from another. How does that help to do that?

Comment: This answers a different question, not the question in the OP.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure how anyone didn't answer this.

You can use double asterisk to deconstruct a dict, and that co-incidentally happens to work inside another dict too.

```
someweirddata = {"hello":"world"}
print({"initial data":"yati yati yata",**someweirddata})
```

output:

```
{'initial data': 'yati yati yata', 'hello': 'world'}
```

This is the same as Javascript's ..., except that it's **

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... The question wants to get specific keys from another dict. How does that help to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
def removekey(mydict, key):
    r = dict(mydict)
    del r[key]
    return r
```

pass mydict dictionary and key to be deleted, returns the remaining dictionary